# Nifi to insert dynamic value to the database after parsing the file from CSV?

Tags: apache-nifi

processor used
GetFile -> SplitRecord -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL

Objective:
To insert a dynamic value to a DB column called list_index
To insert current date to a DB column date
To insert the raw data to a DB column raw_data_text

Comment: Can you supply some sample input, the table definition, and an example? Also have you tried PutDatabaseRecord rather than SplitRecord -> ConvertJSONToSQL -> PutSQL? It does all that for you

Comment: input: first_name, last_name, age
then ill dynamically add value to list_index.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the dynamic value come from? Try GetFile -> UpdateRecord -> PutDatabaseRecord instead. UpdateRecord will let you add a field `list_index` with the value you want (it can use Expression Language as well), and PutDatabaseRecord will then insert all columns as a row for each record.

Comment: Dynamic value should be getting it from csv file like  for instance getting the position number of each record in a csv file before inserting to the database name list_index.